# Procmail to delete mail from senders

Tags: procmail

I'm looking to delete all mail addressed from "root@", where the address could originate from any domain. Am I right in thinking the line below would achieve this? [using sendmail]

:0
* ^From.root*

/dev/null

Or if I wanted to move to a folder, will this work and automatically create the folder (imap syncable)

:0
* ^From.root*

ExampleFolder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will delete the mail :

```
:0
* ^From:.*root@.*
/dev/null
```

Will create the folder and move the mail to it (you still need to subscribe to the folder over IMAP)

```
:0
* ^From:.*root@.*
ExampleFolder
```

Comment: The trailing `.*` is superfluous, albeit mostly harmless. Do you really intend to allow exactly one arbitrary character between `From:` and `root@`?